# Is it safe to combine data for zipcodes across different demographic sets?

Tags: spatial-database, zip-codes, demography

My team is working with demographics data across different data sources (some paid sources and some free data sources available online).

Each of these data sources comes with a shapefile and some attributes associated with each demographic area and could be defined across different cuts of time.

However, when we display these attributes to our end users, we wanted to abstract the multiple datasources concept and show zip codes as a single demographic unit.

We were planning to combine the attributes of all the datasources into one single data source and point that to one of the shapefiles (For the time being, we are willing to look past issues related to granularity or precision in the definition of polygon across these data sources.

However, should we be concerned that the ZIP code to actual geographic area might not be consistent across demographics datasources taken across different cuts in time? E.g. Zip code 12345 used to Map to an area in State A till 2010 but points to an area in State B for all datasets after 2010?

Comment: Yes, you should be concerned that you would be misrepresenting data. Are you wanting to show the most recent data for any given location? If so, let us know what software you're using and we can give you some ideas of how to address the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be so concerned with the zip code itself. Remember that in spatial analysis, location often functions as your primary key. That is, if you have the shapefiles associated with each set of tabular data, then you don't need to sacrifice anything. Instead, simply union all your shapefiles, along with their attributes. You might want to change field names first, so that--for example--the date of an attribute isn't indecipherable to your end users.

Comment: Zip codes are tricky.  Like you said they will change over time, in fact I believe they change rather often (sometimes on a monthly basis) and because of this your results may not be accurate.  Are there other unique fields in this data other than zip code? What time periods are you looking at?   Also can we maybe see a slice of the data you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it should be an issue of concern, especially if you're normalizing your data using geography. There are several different techniques for disggregating data using area weighting models. In addition, if you're actually using Zip Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTA) and the other data are population based, you could use [zip code crosswalk tables](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/zcta_rel_download.html) to distribute your estimates to a more granular geography like Tracts.